# Duplicate key org.jetbrains.jps.model.module.impl.JpsModuleImpl

Tags: java, intellij-idea

my project always was working fine until i opened it today in intelIj and tried to run it i get this error

```
Error:maven-annotations-test:myapp: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key org.jetbrains.jps.model.module.impl.JpsModuleImpl@50eac852
```

it's not a maven project so i don't get what's causing this

Comment: Have you tried to run "File | Invalidate Caches"? Is it possibleto share idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after restarting IDE and reproducing the issue?

Comment: I had to remove the .idea folder and re-import the project again.

Comment: Mine was a maven project, and I got the same error. Joseph's answer worked to resolve it though.

Answer (score 10):

[image: Left upper panel on Intellij IDEA]

Click on **Reimport All Maven Projects** - First icon on the left in the image above.

Worked for me!

Comment: In my case, I had to open the maven tool window to find this button, which was on the right edge of the IntelliJ application window for me near the top, and can also be found in View > Tool Windows > Maven. Once the tool window is open the button you need is apparent from the screenshot.

Comment: Did not work for me

Answer (score 2):

Related to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-225394 - Internal error: (java.lang.IllegalStateException) Duplicate key

> I managed to fix something like this only after closing Intellij and deleting the directory `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.1`
>
> After selecting `Run -> Run` and running `com.appointment.publishing in spring-boot-app` the project works fine for the first time.
>
> After modifying the test file on the project and trying to run it more times, it throws the following exception.
>
> After throwing it, the only way to fix it, is going on `Build -> Rebuild Project`.
>
> However, the problems start happening again if you try to run the project more than one time (after modifying the test file).
>
> ```
> Error:Internal error: (java.lang.IllegalStateException) Duplicate key Validate JSPs in 'spring-boot-appointment-publishing:war exploded'
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key Validate JSPs in 'spring-boot-appointment-publishing:war exploded'
>     at java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$throwingMerger$0(Collectors.java:133)
>     at java.util.HashMap.merge(HashMap.java:1253)
>     at java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$toMap$58(Collectors.java:1320)
>     at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$3ReducingSink.accept(ReduceOps.java:169)
>     at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
>     at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
>     at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
>     at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
>     at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
>     at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
>     at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
>     at org.jetbrains.jps.javaee.build.jspValidation.JspValidationTarget$Type.createLoader(JspValidationTarget.java:156)
>     at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.BuildTargetTypeState.load(BuildTargetTypeState.java:63)
>     at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.BuildTargetTypeState.<init>(BuildTargetTypeState.java:52)
>     at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.BuildTargetsState.getTypeState(BuildTargetsState.java:122)
>     at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.BuildTargetsState.getAverageBuildTime(BuildTargetsState.java:116)
>     at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.checkRebuildRequired(IncProjectBuilder.java:285)
>     at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:167)
>     at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:138)
>     at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:297)
>     at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:130)
>     at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:218)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> ```
>
> IU-201.8538.31, JRE 11.0.7+10-b765.64x64 JetBrains s.r.o., OS Windows 10(amd64) v10.0 , screens 1920x1080

> I noticed following error after invoking Build -> Build Project:
>
> ```
> Error:Internal error: (java.lang.IllegalStateException) Duplicate key emdms-server (attempted merging values org.jetbrains.jps.model.module.impl.JpsModuleImpl@e8df99a and org.jetbrains.jps.model.module.impl.JpsModuleImpl@64b73e7a)
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key emdms-server (attempted merging values org.jetbrains.jps.model.module.impl.JpsModuleImpl@e8df99a and org.jetbrains.jps.model.module.impl.JpsModuleImpl@64b73e7a)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.Collectors.duplicateKeyException(Collectors.java:133)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$uniqKeysMapAccumulator$1(Collectors.java:180)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$3ReducingSink.accept(ReduceOps.java:169)
> at java.base/java.util.AbstractList$RandomAccessSpliterator.forEachRemaining(AbstractList.java:720)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
> at org.jetbrains.jps.maven.model.impl.MavenAnnotationProcessorTargetType.createLoader(MavenAnnotationProcessorTargetType.java:50)
> at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.BuildTargetTypeState.load(BuildTargetTypeState.java:66)
> at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.BuildTargetTypeState.(BuildTargetTypeState.java:55)
> at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.BuildTargetsState.getTypeState(BuildTargetsState.java:110)
> at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.BuildTargetsState.getAverageBuildTime(BuildTargetsState.java:104)
> at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.messages.BuildProgress.(BuildProgress.java:70)
> at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:365)
> at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:178)
> at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:139)
> at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:288)
> at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:121)
> at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:228)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
> ```
>
> IU-192.6817.14, JRE 11.0.4 10-b304.69x64 JetBrains s.r.o, OS Windows 10(amd64) v10.0 , screens 1920x1080
>
> Update: The exception has disappeared after right click on parent pom.xml -> Maven -> Reimport.

Some times just deleing the `IntelliJIdea2020.1` directory was not enough. I had to also delete my `C:\Users\UserName\.m2` directory.

> @Jet Brains Team: The problem is caused by duplicated artifact configuration files. In order to fix it, you need to delete application_name_war_exploded2.xml and application_name_war2.xml files from .idea/artifacts directory.
> Not sure why these duplicating artifacts were produced though. Did you edit artifact configurations manually in File | Project Structure | Artifacts?

Answer (score 0):

I had to right click, hover on **Maven** and click **Download Sources and Documentation**

Solved it for me

Comment: Worked once, but the issue came up again and persisted

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the `~/.m2/repository` dir and [system directory](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#system-directory) did it for me.

**Edit**
The issue kept coming up after clearing both the caches. Well, haha, it was so darn trivial to solve: `Rebuild project`